# Creating table in mysql but the error keeps poping up , what am i doing wrong?

Tags: create-table

![CREATE TABLE ELEB(
ccode integer primary key,
cname varchar(20),
add varchar(25),
oldmr integer,
newmr integer,
unit integer,
tbill integer);][1]

Answer (score 0):

CREATE TABLE ELEB
( 
`ccode` int primary key, 
`cname` varchar(20), 
`add` varchar(25), 
`oldmr` int, 
`newmr` int, 
`unit` int, 
`tbill` int
)